# Deploy SL4 application with localized DLL imports

Tags: silverlight-4.0, localization

I have a VS2010 SL4 project which uses an external Silverlight DLL. The project is localized with multiple RESX files, and the DLL is, too. I usually include external DLLs in my solutions as follows:

1) create a set of virtual folders in my solution like (say the imported DLL is named Sample.dll):

```
  /Lib/Sample/Debug
  /Lib/Sample/Release
```

2) create the same folders structure in the file system and copy under Debug and Release the respective versions of the DLL, so that now I find the following files:

```
  /Lib/Sample/Debug/Sample.dll
  /Lib/Sample/Release/Sample.dll
```

3) add to all the client projects in the solution a reference to */Lib/Sample/Debug/Sample.dll*.

4) open the .csproj file of each project with the added reference, and change the *Debug* part of the path with *$(Configuration)*, so that the right Debug/Release version is picked during build.

Now the question is: in my SL4 solution I can follow the same procedure for importing the language-neutral DLL. But what about its satellite resources? For instance, the French version of the imported DLL is built under subfolder *fr-FR* and named *Sample.resources.dll*. How should I include it correctly? Even If I try to manually add it in the compiled XAP under folder *fr*, it is ignored and the application falls back to its neutral culture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it, here's a recap for whom may be interested:

1. open the *.csproj* file and ensure you add all your desired languages (separated by semicolons) in . For instance, if you support *fr-Fr* add *<SupportedCultures>fr-Fr</SupportedCultures>*.
2. (had to do this manually, I supposed 1. should be enough): once compiled, open your xap (rename it to .zip and open) and add if not present an element like *<AssemblyPart Source="fr-FR/Sample.resources.dll" />* for each imported satellite with resources.

Thanks anyway!